# Which of the Virtualbox services do I need?

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit

I'm using Virtualbox on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.
I found many services loaded at startup related to vbox

- vboxautostart-service
- vboxdrv
- vboxballoonctrl-service
- vboxweb-service

I disabled all of them and now the startup seems faster. Also, I tried to launch VB with all the services disabled and VB runs without fails. So, what are these services? What they do? Can I safely run VB without launching them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I found online
 - vboxautostart-service: manage some autostart options like configuration file, deny access to users, ...
 - vboxdrv: the only one needed if you want to run virtualbox in the traditional way!
 - vboxweb-service: needed if you want to use phpVirtualBox to access your VB machine from a remote terminal 
 - vboxballoonctrl-service:

> Starting with VirtualBox 4.0.8 a new host executable called VBoxBalloonCtrl is available to automatically take care of a VM's
>   configured memory balloon (see Section 4.8.1, “Memory ballooning” for
>   an introduction to memory ballooning). This is especially useful for
>   server environments where VMs may dynamically require more or less
>   memory during runtime.
>
> VBoxBalloonCtrl periodically checks a VM's current memory balloon and
>   its free guest RAM and automatically adjusts the current memory
>   balloon by inflating or deflating it accordingly. This handling only
>   applies to running VMs having recent Guest Additions installed.